# AngularJS -> Java: POST/PUT request results in 'Preflight request doesn't pass access control check'

Tags: java, angularjs, express, dropwizard

From searching around for the issue I have figured out this has to do with CORS. I'm not sure what the best way to solve it would be.

I have a Java web service running that has various GET/POST/PUT/DELETE resources. It is a dropwizard application that uses jersey/jax-rs. I decided to build a GUI app for it using AngularJS. I can make a GET request fine but when I try to make a POST or PUT request I get this error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

The part of the angular code making the PUT looks like this:

```
$http.put(url, data).
then(function(response) {
    $scope.message = response.data;
```

It is being served with express:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization, Accept');   next(); });

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html')); });

app.listen(8080); console.log("running on 8080");
```

As mentioned, the Java service has different resources, for example:

```
@PUT
@Path("/insert/{operation}/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response addEntry ...
```

And as part of the response I added some headers that other posts/questions suggested:

```
public static Response success(String content) {
    CustomResponse skeletonRsponse = response(content);
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(skeletonRsponse.getContent())
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
        .build();
}
```

But the error persists. 
I noticed from looking at the server logs that the request from the Angular app is being sent as

> [25/Jan/2018:00:11:49 +0000] "OPTIONS..."

rather than "PUT..."

From my understanding of CORS and how angular $http works (which is limited) a 'OPTIONS' request is sent and if all is good there then the actual request is sent. So what should I do about this? One thought I had was to make @Options resources that return the proper headers but that seems like it would not be optimal since I'd have to create one for each existing resource to make up with the right paths.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP `OPTIONS` method is used to describe the communication options for the target resource. Refer [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS).

`OPTIONS` request doesn't need to be implemented. Just try adding `OPTIONS` in header value of `“Access-Control-Allow-Methods”` in your response.

Comment: Add it in the Java Service when the Response is being constructed?

Comment: Yes, where you have added other HTTP Methods - GET, POST, PUT and DELETE

Comment: OK I will try that. My only concern is that since it is coming as 'OPTIONS' none of the resources will recognize it since they are annotated with POST, PUT, etc. but not OPTIONS.

Comment: Please see my updated answer for your doubts. Also, let me know if it solved your problem. If yes, please accept the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter`. This is Kotlin code but i think you can sort it out:

```
override fun run(configuration: BackendConfig, environment: Environment) {
    // ...
    addServletFilter(CrossOriginFilter::class.java, environment).apply {
        setInitParameter("allowedOrigins", "*")
        setInitParameter("allowedHeaders", "Content-Type,Accept,Origin," + CsrfProtectionFilter.HEADER_NAME)
        setInitParameter("allowedMethods", "OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,HEAD")
    }
}

private fun addServletFilter(filterClass: Class<out Filter>, environment: Environment): FilterRegistration.Dynamic {
    val filter = environment.servlets().addFilter(filterClass.simpleName, filterClass)
    filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType::class.java), true, environment.jersey().urlPattern)
    return filter
}
```

PS. I'm actually about to create a "filters" bundle that configures useful filters in DropWizard with reasonable defaults, but it's not ready yet!